# What is the difference between 'using' a parent class constructor and creating a new one in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, using

So recently i have been working on a basic math library in c++ and decided to make template classes and inherited, specialised classes, for example Vector.

I have had some problems with linking default constructor of parent class without having the need to make a new one.
I can see that the **using** keyword also allows me to use any of the base class constructors that I want, but the other solution (the one below) seems more elegant.

```
    template<typename type>
    class Vector3D : public Vector<type, 3>
    {
    public:
        /// Telling compiler to use constructors of parent class Vector
        using Vector<type, 3>::Vector;

        Vector3D() : KMath::Vector<type, 3>() {}
```

As I see that both of these approaches work, I'm curious what are the differences between those and if any of these is better/more widely used?

Edit: For explicity I will paste the parent class here:

```
    template<typename type, unsigned int SIZE>
    class Vector
    {
    protected:
        type vectorTuple[SIZE];

    public:
        explicit Vector()
        {
            unsigned int i;
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
            {
                vectorTuple[i] = 0.0;
            }
        }

        explicit Vector(type arr[SIZE])
        {
            unsigned int i;
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
            {
                vectorTuple[i] = arr[i];
            }
        }
    ...
    };
```

My problem was not only with the default constructor being called, but also with the other one, as without the **using** keyword compiler would return an error if I attemted

```
double arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
Vector3D<double> vec(arr);
```

Without the **using** keyword or creating the same kind of constructor in the derived class, the code would obviously not work. I have seen this solution somewhere on the web and was just curious to see if it has any implications.

Comment: If you think the more verbose one is more elegant, by all means do a lot of avoidable redundant typing. I'm not sure why you even need the `using` though, for a default constructor.

Comment: I don't think your example illustrates the problem you are having with linking.  You could leave out both the `using` and the `Vector3D` constructor in this case, with no change in meaning.  The base class is a template, so if you are having linker problems it has something to do with instantiation; e.g. the bodies are not present in the header.  I can think of a case that would have this issue, but it involves multiple source files and the derived class constructor that's explicitly written has its body in a CPP file (not H file) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - in your snippet, you do not need either. Your constructors are default constructors, do not use arguments and you could easily remove `using` declaration, as well as a explicit default constructor.

In more general case, `using` declaration for base constructor makes it visible in the child class (otherwise it is hidden by the implicit child's class default constructor).

When you employ it, base class constructors become available in the child class, and allow one to construct child class by calling one of the base's constructors with matching signature.

For example:

```
struct Base {
    Base(int );
};

struct Derived : Base {
    // using Base::Base;
};

void foo() {
    Derived d{1}; // Fails unless using directive is uncommented above
}
```

This approach is viable when derived classes do not need to perform any initialization of their own, and simply want to make available base construction.

Please note, `using` base's constructor doesn't block derived classes from creating their own. For example:

```
struct Base {
    Base(int );
};

struct Derived : Base {
    using Base::Base;
    Derived(const char* str);
};
```

In the example above, `Dervived d{1}` will call `Base:Base(int )`, while `Derived d{"hello"}` will call `Derived::Derived(const char*)`

On the other hand, explicitly calling base constructors from derived constructors is usable when there is some logic associated with derived class constructor - i.e. non-default member initialization without default initializers, non-trivial body, etc. For example:

```
struct Base {
    Base(int );
};

struct Derived : Base {
    Derived(int x) : Base(x), own(x + 5) { }
    int own;
};
```

In this case, `Derived` constructor needs to do two things - call `Base` with `int` argument and initialize `own`. So `using` Base's constructor would not be appropriate, as it would leave `own` uninitialized.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for explanation, I think it explains the whole idea to me really well. It is true that my example is really bad as I didn't even show Vector class and the problem would be better shown this way (Vector has more than one default constructor). 
But now there is no need to since your explanations seems to make sense to me and really exhausted the topic. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

If we are comparing employing `using` vs manually redeclaring the same constructors and forwarding them explicitly to the base class, then both are effectively equivalent as far as the resulting code is concerned. However, there is a real difference when looking at the codebase as a living, evolving entity:

It changes the logical relationship between the construction of the two classes that is being expressed by the code.

The two following statements do not mean the same thing:

- "This class has the same constructors as its parent, and possibly a few more as well."
- "This class has these constructors, some of which coincidentally happen to be the same as its parent *right now*."

For example: Let's say a new constructor to `Vector<size, type>` is introduced 6 months from now. With `using`, `Vector3<type>` will inherit that constructor implicitly without any additional refactoring. Whether that would be desirable or not is the distinguishing factor that determines which approach is appropriate.

Writing good code is not just about making a program behave reliably in a certain way. It's also about making sure the program's behaviour *stays* stable as it evolves over long periods of time.

Comment: It just doesn't "change logical relationship". It makes base's constructors visible, that all. One can make base's constructor visible **and** have additional child constructors.

Comment: @SergeyA I interpreted OP's question as comparing the alternative of employing `using` vs manually dispatching the same constructors, and my answer is scoped around that. I'll add the clarification.